# Angular unifiend method updates info but incorrect

Tags: angular

I want to make this method unified. Array and form arguments are private. I have another method without arguments, where all the arguments are in code. But if I use this unified method the app is not working properly.
The unified method:

```
createContragent(form: FormGroup, modalId: string, array: any): void {
const data = {
  customerName: form.value.name as string,
  customerType: form.value.type as string
};
this.service.saveUserCustomer(data).subscribe(response => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
    this.hideModal(modalId);
    form.reset();
    array.pop();
    this.service.getAllUserCustomer().subscribe(agents => {
      if (agents.status === 200) {
        array = agents.body;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

}
}

Not unified method:

```
 createNewExpressSenderContragent(): void {
// Write something
const data = {
  customerName: this.newExpressSenderContragent.value.name as string,
  customerType: this.newExpressSenderContragent.value.type as string
};

this.service.saveUserCustomer(data).subscribe(response => {
  if (response.status === 200) {
    this.hideModal('new-express-sender-contragent');
    this.newExpressSenderContragent.reset();
    this.expressSenderAgents.pop();
    this.service.getAllUserCustomer().subscribe(agents => {
      if (agents.status === 200) {
        this.expressSenderAgents = agents.body;
      }
    });
  }
});
```

}
It sends a request, but this.expressSenderAgents have no update on the fly if I use unified method. What should I do?

Comment: What's the issue? The customer data in your unified method is not as expected, so it won't save?

Comment: It doesn't update  this.expressSenderAgents.